# Turning a db result set into a valid json with php

Tags: php, arrays, json, associative-array

In my php I am running a simple query which returns a resultset(0 or many) from the database I have.

Currently on the fronted the rersult looks like this :

```
name: Smoothie description: Banana Smothie name: Phad Thai description: Noodles with shrimps name: Noodles description: Noodles with noodles.
```

The string can also look like this, aka `name: Smoothie description: Banana Smothie` or with more entries, like in the  example above.

The code below gives me this  :

```
[{"name":"Smoothie","description":"Banana Smothie"}][{"name":"Phad Thai","description":"Noodles with shrimps"}]
```

What I'd like to have is, so it can be just one json object :

```
 [{"name":"Smoothie","description":"Banana Smothie"},{"name":"Phad Thai","description":"Noodles with shrimps"}]
```

This is my php :

```
    <?php
 include_once 'db/dbconnect.php';
 $input = json_decode(stripcslashes($_POST['data']));

 for ($i=0; $i < count($input); $i++) {
     $stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT recipes.recipeName, recipes.recipeDescription FROM ingredients, recipes, recipesingredients WHERE recipes.recipeId = recipesingredients.recipeIdFK AND recipesingredients.ingredientIdFK = ingredients.IngredientId AND ingredients.ingredientName = ?");
     $stmt->bind_param("s", $input[$i]);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->store_result();
     $stmt->bind_result($db_recipe_name, $db_recipe_description);

     $rslt = array();
     $arr = 0;
     while ($stmt->fetch()) {
         $rslt[$arr] = array('name' => $db_recipe_name, 'description' => $db_recipe_description);
         $arr++;
     }
     $jsonRslt = json_encode($rslt);
     echo $jsonRslt;
 }
 ?>
```

Can someone help me making this to a one json object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating new arrays that you json_encode and echo inside the loop, create one before the loop and add each object to it.

Example:

```
<?php
include_once 'db/dbconnect.php';
$input = json_decode(stripcslashes($_POST['data']));

// Create an array before the loop
$json = [];

for ($i=0; $i < count($input); $i++) {
    $stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT recipes.recipeName, recipes.recipeDescription FROM ingredients, recipes, recipesingredients WHERE recipes.recipeId = recipesingredients.recipeIdFK AND recipesingredients.ingredientIdFK = ingredients.IngredientId AND ingredients.ingredientName = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $input[$i]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($db_recipe_name, $db_recipe_description);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        // Add each element to the main array
        $json[] = array('name' => $db_recipe_name, 'description' => $db_recipe_description);
    }
}

// json_encode and echo the main array
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `for` loop, the `$rslt` array is re-initialized every time for each `i` which is why you are getting multiple JSON objects instead of a single one.

You need to initialize the `$rslt` outside the `for` loop and encode it into JSON after the `for` loop.

```
<?php
 include_once 'db/dbconnect.php';
 $input = json_decode(stripcslashes($_POST['data']));

 // Initialize array here
 $rslt = array();
 $arr = 0;

 for ($i=0; $i < count($input); $i++) {
     $stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT recipes.recipeName, recipes.recipeDescription FROM ingredients, recipes, recipesingredients WHERE recipes.recipeId = recipesingredients.recipeIdFK AND recipesingredients.ingredientIdFK = ingredients.IngredientId AND ingredients.ingredientName = ?");
     $stmt->bind_param("s", $input[$i]);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->store_result();
     $stmt->bind_result($db_recipe_name, $db_recipe_description);

     while ($stmt->fetch()) {
         $rslt[$arr] = array('name' => $db_recipe_name, 'description' => $db_recipe_description);
         $arr++;
     }
 }

 // encode into JSON
 $jsonRslt = json_encode($rslt);
 echo $jsonRslt;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create php array inside for loop. Don't json encode / echo inside loop. Echo only final resulting php array out side outer for loop.  Also, set response header to json.  - sorry for typo. Answered from mobile.